# How to store data to temp table from Stored Procedure With Output parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which return result by setting multiple output parameter. I want to store those output parameter values to temp table, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table as follows:

```
create table #temp_table_name
(
    firstOutputParam int,
    secondOutputParam varchar(50), 
    thirdOutputParam varchar(150)
)
```

Since the stored procedure is executing, the temp table will remain valid until the end of the execution.